# message error implementing google maps in ionic (touchstart,touchmove)

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, ionic4, ionic-native

I use cordova geolocation and the google maps javascript api, and a simple implementation and still keep the error, when trying to zoom in or out.
the problem appears when I move and zoomed the map.
**
 It is good to mention that this message appears when I connect the mobile for real time debugging with
ionic cordova run android -L
and exploring console messages with remote devices using chrome
 chrome://inspect/#devices

[image]

```
<pre>
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation, Geoposition } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { LoadingController, IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';
declare var google: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mapa',
  templateUrl: './mapa.page.html',
  styleUrls:['./mapa.page.scss'],
})
export class MapaPage implements OnInit {
  map: any;
  marker: any;
  @ViewChild(IonSlides, { static: true }) slide: IonSlides;
  @ViewChild('map', { read: ElementRef, static: false }) mapRef: ElementRef;
  constructor(
    private geolocation: Geolocation,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {  }
  ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.showMap();
  }
  async showMap() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create();
    loading.present();
    const myLatLng = await this.getLocation();
    const options = {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, options);
    loading.dismiss();
  }
</pre>
```

Comment: did you solve the issue? I have a similar problem